# laptop keyboard buttons and power button is not working

Tags: laptop, keyboard, bios

My laptop keyboard is behaving randomly. Two days back Q,W,E,R,T have stopped working,now they are working but E,N,B,C,X,Space bar have gone bad.

my power button is not working, for starting laptop i need to remove and replace the cmos battery.I have changed cmos battery and updated bios as stated in some answers here.

These problems started when i opened my laptop for changing dead fan.I remember i didn't do anything to power button.

laptop details--dell Inspiron 1545 ubuntu 14.10

please, someone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Some suggestion: 1 Reboot and try in Safe Mode. 
If you are a Microsoft Windows user and specific keys malfunction in all programs, reboot you computer and try the keys in Safe Mode.

2 Clean the keyboard. 
Remove the key that isn't working from the keyboard and clean it. In some situations, dirt, hair, dust, and other debris can obstruct keys or cause them to malfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most likely dislodged the power cable and partially dislodged the keyboard cable. (its possible you have damaged the cables - but it looks to me like they are zif sockets so I think you should be OK).   The solution would possibly be to try and reseat these cables.

If you look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Gt2i_yS3I) starting at 02:50  (actually at 02:56), you will see the 2 cables I am referring to.

Comment: Finally got the time to open the laptop, after carefully checking found that power cable's one wire was broken. Got it changed, and it's working again.       But no luck with keyboard, it's still randomly not working.